# Replacing Numpy elements with the closest if condition is met

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I have a large numpy array that I need to manipulate so that each element is within a certain range.

I can identify the elements that are invalid

```
v[np.where(v>upper_lim)]
v[np.where(v<lower_lim)]
```

or more simply by:

```
v[v>upper_lim]
v[v<lower_lim]
```

Now I would like to replace each element which meets this condition with the closest (earlier) samples available for which the condition was met.

e.g.

```
upper_lim=10
lower_lim=1
v=[1,-77,3,4,5,13213,6,7,8,1024]
```

should give

```
v=[1,1,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8]
```

when no elements are available **before** the invalid value, I would need to replace with the next valid element

so

```
upper_lim=10
lower_lim=1
v=[-7,1,2,3,-77]
```

should give

```
v=[1,1,2,3,3]
```

A possible solution using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
v=pd.DataFrame(v)
v[v>ul]=np.nan
v[v<ll]=np.nan
v=v.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
v=v.flatten()
```

but using `pandas` is not an option for me

Comment: one way to do this, replace the invalid values by NaN and use bfill()/ffill() methods.

Comment: Just a side-note: yopu don't need `where`, you can just use `v[v>upper_lim]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandas has padding ability, which is what you are describing, but you would have to cast your array as a float because numpy int arrays cannot hold `np.nan` values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

upper = 10
lower = 1
v=np.array([1,-77,3,4,5,13213,6,7,8,1024])
s = pd.Series(v)
s[~((s>lower) & (s<upper))] = np.nan
s = s.fillna(method='pad')
# at this point the series is padded but the values are floats instead of 
# ints,  you can cast back to an int array if you wish

v2 = s.values.astype(int)
v2
# outputs:
array([1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8])
```

update:

a numpy only solution

```
# first we identify elements that are out of bounds and need to be filled from the data
mask = (v<lower) | (v>upper)
oob = np.where(mask)[0]

# for each oob value, we calculate the index that provides the fill-value using a forward fill or backward fill
def fillidx(i, mask_oob):
    try:
        if i == 0 or np.all(mask_oob[:i]): 
        # all elements from start are oob
            raise IndexError()
        n = -1 * (1 + np.argmin(mask_oob[:i][::-1]))
    except (IndexError):
        n = 1 + np.argmin(mask_oob[i+1:])
    return i + n


fill = [fillidx(i, mask) for i in oob]
v[mask] = v[fill]
print(v)
```

with the first test array `v = np.array([1,-77,3,4,5,13213,6,7,8,1024])`, the following is output:

```
[1 1 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8]
```

with the second test array `v = np.array([-7,1,2,3,-77])` the following is output:

```
[1 1 2 3 3]
```

with an array where consecutive values are out of bounds and the first few elements are also out of bounds, i.e. `v = np.array([-200,20,1,-77,3,4,5,13213,-200,6,7,8,1024])` we get the following output:

```
[1 1 1 1 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 8]
```

Comment: yes, but you'd have to write your own `fillna` function.

Comment: @ErroriSalvo, see updated answer for a numpy only solution

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in comments,

```
v=[1,-77,3,4,5,13213,6,7,8,1024]
df=pd.DataFrame(v)

df[df>ul]=np.nan
df[df<ll]=np.nan
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
v=np.array(df[0])
```

output:

```
array([ 1.,  1.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  8.])
```

Comment: what if  upper_lim=1e14?

Comment: @ErroriSalvo then this solution will make a huge `a` array =/

Comment: that's what I was pointing at :) also, iterating over it won't be very efficient